# Naturally definable order relations

Tags: set-theory, relations, ordinals

Each and every function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ between two totally ordered sets $(X,\leq_X), (Y,\leq_Y)$ induces a relation $\preceq$ on $X$ by

$$x \preceq x' :\equiv \begin{cases} x &\leq_X x' &\mbox{if } &f(x) = f(x') \\
f(x) &\leq_Y f(x') &\mbox{if } &f(x) \neq f(x')  \end{cases} 
$$

> Is this relation $\preceq$ more "natural" than other relations
>   definable over $\leq_X$, $\leq_Y$?

---

> Is $\preceq$ automatically a total order? Or:  Which extra conditions do $\leq_X$, $\leq_Y$ have to
>   fulfill such that $\preceq$ is a total order?

---

> Assume that $\leq_X$, $\leq_Y$ are *well*-orders. Which conditions do they have to
>   fulfill such that $\preceq$ is a *well*-order again?

Comment: Neat idea. The way I understand it, this is basically the result of taking the pullback $f^*(\leq_Y)$ defined by $f^*(\leq_Y)(x',x) \iff f(x') \leq_Y x$, and then replacing each equivalence class of $f^*(\leq_Y)$ with the structure induced by $\leq_X$. Anyway, its pretty cool if you ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\le$ be the lexicographic order on $Y\times X$: $\langle y_0,x_0\rangle\le\langle y_1,x_1\rangle$ iff either $y_0\le_Y y_1$, or $y_0=y_1$ and $x_0\le_X x_1$. Then the map

$$X\to Y\times X:x\mapsto\langle f(x),x\rangle$$

is an order-isomorphism between $\langle X,\preceq\rangle$ and $\langle f^{-1},f^{-1}\,\cap\le\rangle$. (I view $f$ as a subset of $X\times Y$.) Thus, $\preceq$ is always a linear order. If $\le_X$ and $\le_Y$ are well-orders, so is $\le$, and therefore so is $\preceq$.